# Does closed-form Green function exist for heat conduction and convection in a slab?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, greens-function

I am wondering if Green function exists for heat conduction and convection in a slab. The problem can be expressed as,
$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = k\frac{\partial ^2T}{\partial x^2}-v\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}
$$

Boundary condition:
$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}=g(t), x = 0, t>0
$$
$$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}=0, x = L, t>0
$$

If no Green function exists for such a problem, how about the semi-infinite media by changing the right boundary at $L$ to $\infty$. I know the Green functions for heat conduction problem with arbitrary boundary condition are well documented, but the convection problem is not. I found some literature that gave the Green function in frequency domain considering the heat convection, but I didn't find a closed form in temporal domain. I appreciate for any comments on this problem. Thanks in advance.